# Is there a way for Solr/Lucene to return the ranks of selected documents instead of full results?

Tags: solr, lucene, rank

I am interested in querying Solr with query *q* and charting its recall of a set of documents *D* when {10, 20, 30, ...} documents are returned.

Currently, I am having the full results, i.e. a list of docids returned (through solrpy), and iterate through it to find the ranks of *D*, i.e. a mapping from *D* to their indices in the search results. I do not strictly require the mapping, only mapped ranks.

Is there a way to have Solr/Lucene return ranks for a set of IDs instead of the full results?

Other ways of approaching this problem:

- For a query, return the rank of document *d*
- For a query up to a specified rank, return whether or not document *d* is present
- From a query *q1* result up to a specified number of records, return the number of records matched by another query *q2*

Comment: +1ed it for such an unusual question. May I ask what problem you intend to solve?\

Comment: Generally, I want to chart Solr's recall of selected documents under different queries.

More specifically, I am analysing data collected for computational linguistics work, which involves finding the best article for a linguistically-constrained query. I need to be able to construct different queries and determine how well they solve my problem.

Comment: Hmm, using Lucene library seems a better bet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No I cannot think of a SOLR or Lucene way to do this. 
I think the simplest solution here is to program this yourself with a simple HashSet...

Comment: How would a hash help? Let's say I query the index with sorting on one field, and I would like to know at what rank a certain document would be in the list.

Comment: It is probably what you are already doing: put all D's codIDs into a (HashSet) set, then iterate over the SOLR result set and check if the ID is in your set. User a SOLR cursor if you are going deep into the result set (many pages).

Answer (score 5):

You can retrieve rank by `score` field.

Append `&fl=KeyFieldName,score` to retrieve document id and score to your query. If you need all fields append `&fl=*,score` to your query.

See http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrRelevancyFAQ#How_can_I_see_the_relevancy_scores_for_search_results for details.

Comment: The score field gives me more information than I need. I don't actually need the list results, I just need to know at what rank a particular result appears. `&fl=KeyFieldName` would therefore be sufficient for me to then look through the results. But if there are thousands of results, that is much more information being passed back from the server than needs to be, just to know at what rank a certain KeyFieldName value appears.