# Ranking or position of a solr document in search results

Tags: solr, full-text-search, position

I need to list the ranking (or position, as you might prefer) or each document after a query in solr. the thing i wanna see is something like this:

```
<doc>
    <int name="field1">1</int>
    <str name="someotherfield">blabla</str>
    <int name="position">1</int>
</doc>
<doc>
    <int name="field1">2</int>
    <str name="someotherfield">blabla</str>
    <int name="position">2</int>
</doc>
<doc>
    <int name="field1">3</int>
    <str name="someotherfield">blabla</str>
    <int name="position">3</int>
</doc>
```

is this possible? or i need to implement or find a plugin?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easiest to calculate on the front-end? Or do you need the position in the raw XML results?

Comment: I need the position in whole result list, i have thought about frontend thing too... but what happens in case of paging? then for each result you would see ranks from 1 to 10 or 15 or whatever your page size is? I heard some stuff about XSLT functions within Solr but I am not sure how to use it

Comment: In the case of paging, simply add the value of the `start` param to the rank.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well after digging the source code, I am now able to see dynamic positions for each different search.. I have simply added a position function to `DocIterator` and implemented in in subclasses. Then I have added a control block in `ReturnFields` for checking if fl has position in it. It is working in a similar way with `score`. and the last thing to do was adding a custom augmenter class like `PositionAugmenter` - similar to `ScoreAugmenter`. Then I am done :)

thank you for *David Faber* for giving me idea of dealing with the results of raw XML

Answer (score -2):

List a field `position` (among other things) in results:

```
...&fl=field1,field2,position
```

Sort by  `position`

```
...&sort=position desc
```

Refer them here : http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters#sort

Comment: i guess you are missing some point.. first there is no field named position therefore fl doesnt return anything for position, and also for sorting i am getting "sort param field cant be found:position" for sorting function (I am using the example data, by the way) so your answer is not useful actually... any other ideas?

Comment: I'm not aware of any Solr pseudo-field called position. I think the OP wants the position (or *rank*) based on whatever his sort might be.

Comment: i am aware that the ultimate position is defined by score field, but the point is how to get position by using pure score field which is a float value actually?

Comment: I guess you mean  something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7924146/is-there-a-way-for-solr-lucene-to-return-the-ranks-of-selected-documents-instead which is one result when you search here for __solr rank of a document__. I dont know this stuff at all, but solr exposes the TF-IDF of documents as functions